# Ansible + SSH + private Git

Tags: git, ssh, ansible

I've tried almost everything, but still can't believe I can be so dumb.

I do have:

- git with private repo
- vps - trying to control with ansible
- control machine - mac os

I do have id_rsa & id_rsa.pub key on my mac
I can ssh to vps without the password from my mac
I can run ansible-playbook from my mac to control vps.

But I can't figure out how to 'git clone' my private repo from vps machine.

I ssh-copy-id from my mac to vps - it's there.
I can work with git from my mac - the same id_rsa key.

How to tell git to authorize/allow clone from vps without copying my private id_rsa from mac onto vps or generating side key just for github?

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up [SSH agent forwarding](https://developer.github.com/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/).

In short:

1. enable agent forwarding on the VPS machine (SSHD config)
2. tell Ansible to connect with agent forwarding option enabled

   for example in `ansible.cfg`, section `[ssh_connection]`, add `-o ForwardAgent=yes` value `ssh_args`.

   or in `~/.ssh/config`:

   ```
    Host <VPS_address>
      ForwardAgent yes
   ```
3. ensure SSH agent is running and has the keys configured:

   ```
   eval `ssh-agent -s`
   ssh-add
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it may be related but there you go:

```
- name: Add host to ssh_config
  community.general.ssh_config:
    host: github.com
    hostname: github.com
    user: vagrant
    identity_file: "/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

[Ansible doc reference](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ssh_config_module.html#ansible-collections-community-general-ssh-config-module)